# Python requests: запрос не отправляется через прокси

Tags: python, proxy

Я хочу отправить нужный запрос через прокси на питоне. Код примерно такой:

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0',
        'X-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
        'X-remote-ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'X-originating-IP': '127.0.0.1',
        'X-remote-addr': '127.0.0.1'
    }
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
    }

    response = requests.post(url=url, headers = headers, data=data, proxies = proxies)
```

Я захотел убедиться в том, что запрос действительно идет через прокси, и по адресу 127.0.0.1:8080 запустил прокси Burp Suite. И когда я выполняю свой скрипт, то burp suite ничего не перехватывает, несмотря на то, что запрос уходит на сервер. То есть отправка через прокси не работает. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: `'http:':` и `'https:':`, двоеточие вроде не ставится таким образом. `'http':` и `'https':`

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn да, спасибо, поправил, но даже после этого burp suite все равно не перехватывает запрос через прокси. То есть передача запроса через прокси не работает. Странно, что питон несмотря на это все равно отправляет запрос на сервер. Я думаю, что если требуется отправлять запрос именно через прокси, а это не получилось, то не надо отправлять запрос вообще

Comment: Все, поправил. Заработало

Comment: А что в итоге было то?

Comment: Burp Suite запускает HTTP прокси. Он не умеет работать с HTTPS, поэтому ничего не отображалось